# Routing HTTP static content requests through Zuul

Tags: apache, webserver, netflix-zuul

I have a Microservice project which uses Zuul as a gateway for API requests. The User Interface web content is hosted on an Apache HTTP server outside Zuul.

Now I would like to route the Web server content through Zuul instead of exposing the service directly

How can I do this?

Zuul does not seem to support web content routing to Apache Server. I have read that this can be done by hosting it and exposing the web content as a Spring project...but that is too overkill

Please let me know if any solutions exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around I was finally able to achieve this

First I built the angular application like this

```
ng build --deploy-url appgateway/ --base-href ui/
```

which would add an appgateway prefix before the static content urls

After that I configured route in zuul configuration like this

```
routes:
  ui:
    path: /ui/**
    url: http://localhost:8080/ui/
    stripPrefix: false
```

Finally I was able to access the application though gateway URL at

```
http://localhost:8090/appgateway/ui/
```